# How to run Octave from a Notepad++ file line by line or by sections?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, notepad++, octave, line-by-line

I am looking for a way to have my Notepad++ window open for editing my code and run it line by line or by sections (more than 1 line) while I am editing. It would be like having a real IDE; the output could be shown in the same window (Notepad++) or directly in the Octave window.

I have tried what many many sites say. That is, writing this:

```
C:\Software\Octave-3.6.4\bin\Octave\Octave-3.6.5.exe  "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"
```

in the Run window in Notepad++, saving and giving it a shortcut. However, it is still not working. When I tried to run it, the black window starts showing-up but then it disappears and nothing else happens. In my Notepad++ window I have only one line (for now) where I have tried just "b=4" or "3*4". I have done this with and without semicolon at the end. Nothing happens.

I have Windows 8.0, Notepad 6.5.5 and Octave-3.6.4. I already change the octaverc file in Octave to make it work with Notepad++. I have work already only in the command line in Octave and is working fine. The Octave I installed was exactly "octave-3.6.4-vs2010-setup", it says it was compiled for Visual Studio 10. Is that the reason why this is not working?

Any help will be appreciated...

Comment: you said you you are running Octave 3.6.5 but there is no such version. If changing editor is an option, the new version of Octave 3.8.1 has already been released and it has an IDE with that feature. The IDE is still experimental though.

Comment: Sorry, I just corrected it, it's Octave 3.6.4. And thanks for your advice. I know about it but for now I prefer to stay with the 3.6.4.

Answer (score 0):

- regarding Octave not processing the command: use supposed command line outside the N++ and see if it works. If not, find a way to make it working, then transfer it back to N++ (and use the token `"$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"` instead of concrete filename)
- regarding running the code in smaller portions: if you app can accept the code directly in the command line (SQL command line tools I use can do this), then you can use token `"$(CURRENT_WORD)"` what stands for content of current **selection** ([all tokens are in wiki](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=External_Programs))